# How to resolve 2 possible authenticators error in Laravel SMTP

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am trying to send mail. But I am receiving an error stating that:-

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   \"abcmail@gmail.com\" using 2 possible authenticators

I have even turned on allow less secure app in my gmail account.

Also, here is the code in my `.env` file:-

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abcmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=12345
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: It is failed to authenticate check the password again

Comment: password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below settings in config/mail.php

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

and In .eve add

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Use SSL for send mail threw SMTP

Comment: Thanks alot. I have tried this also, unfortunately, it did not work. Instead, it says Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

Comment: Ok now you need to allow less security in your google account, It seems work